# Stop giving [untagged] useless usage guidance

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleaning, tag-wiki, suggested-edits

I've noticed a particular user* suggesting edits (of approximately the same content every time, asking users to refrain from tagging with it and explaining the purpose) to the [untagged](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) wiki and usage guidance every so often. These are usually accepted, but of course, the tag is then automatically deleted (within days at most) once all questions are retagged.

These repeated suggestions seem to me to be at best quite useless, and at worst borderline abusive, bumming a little free rep (which is *not* removed when the tag is, unlike suggestions on posts) for no actual benefit to the site. They're useless because [untagged](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) is just a feature of the software, and [cannot be added to questions manually anyway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122841/do-not-allow-users-to-tag-questions-with-untagged).

<sub>**It doesn't really matter who, although I'm sure with a bit of digging one could figure it out.*</sub>

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth it to as SE if they can block editing of this tag at all? Or if they can create a network-wide wiki for it with an explanation of its purpose and that it's not supposed to be a permanent tag?

Comment: @Catija: Actually, turns out it's not necessary. Gonna add a link in a sec for why.

Comment: Wow!  They made it a lot of times! :-)  And they alternate between two different descriptions.  Does it prevent them from re-creating it with the same description twice in a row?

Comment: @snailboat: I'm not sure; they might just be recreating from memory or something.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111508/215040